# Google App script onEdit function is not taking input from a cell with formula

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to automatically change the font color of a cell based on the advancement. So basically what i am thinking of is that if the advancement is 20% the color is gray if it is 45% the color changes.

here is the function :

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var range = e.range;
  var spreadSheet = e.source;
  var sheetName = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var inputValue = e.value;
  Logger.log(e.oldValue);
  Logger.log(inputValue);
  
  if(sheetName == 'Scoreboard' && column == 2 && row == 2)
  {  
    
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Scoreboard').getRange('A2').setValue([inputValue]);    
    if(inputValue < 10){
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Scoreboard').getRange('M6').setFontColor("black").setFontWeight("initial");
  } else if( inputValue >= 10 && inputValue < 20 ){
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Scoreboard').getRange('M6').setFontColor("dimgray").setFontWeight("initial");
  } else if( inputValue >= 20 && inputValue < 40 ){
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Scoreboard').getRange('M6').setFontColor("silver").setFontWeight("initial");
  } else if( inputValue >= 40 && inputValue < 60 ){
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Scoreboard').getRange('M6').setFontColor("palegoldenrod").setFontWeight("initial");
  } else if( inputValue >= 60 && inputValue < 80 ){
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Scoreboard').getRange('M6').setFontColor("khaki").setFontWeight("initial");
  } else if( inputValue >= 80 && inputValue < 100 ){
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Scoreboard').getRange('M6').setFontColor("yellow").setFontWeight("initial");
  } else if( inputValue == 100 ){
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Scoreboard').getRange('M6').setFontColor("yellow").setFontWeight("bold");    
  }
  } 
}
```

First I tried to let the changement of the cell (2,2) manually, So when i change the advancement manually the color of the font in M6 changes automatically,

The problem i am having is that in the cell (2,2) I need to put this formula that calculate the average of the advancement in each project :

```
=AVERAGE('2S VPs Plans'!H114,'2S VPs Plans'!H92,'2S VPs Plans'!H70,'2S VPs Plans'!H48,'2S VPs Plans'!H26)
```

When i go back to the tab "2S VPs Plans" and keep changing the 4 inputs in order to change the average, I got nothing and color does not change.

I believe the function read the cell (2,2) as empty when i add a formula in it. I am not sure but if it is the case, please if you can help make it happen. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason you're attempting this via code instead of conditional formatting?

Comment: The edit is in 2S VP Plans!H..`e` refers only to that edit and not your formulas anywhere else

Comment: @chillin as far as i know, the if statement in the conditional formatting must be in the same cell that will change, which is not the case for me...

Comment: @AimenQaissouni "as far as i know, the if statement in the conditional formatting..." this is wrong. I suggest you to post a question about how to use Google Sheets built-in conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets / Apps Script *on edit* triggers are triggered by changes made by user through the Google Sheets UI. The on edit event object range property will hold the range that was edited.

Knowwing the above you could include some conditional expressions to check if any of the cells referred in your formula have being edited. Example:

```js
function onEdit(e){
  var name = e.range.getSheet().getName();
  var a1Notation = e.range.getA1Notation();
  var a1Notations = ['H114','H92','H70','H48','H26'];
  if( name === '2S VPs Plans' && a1Notations.indexOf(a1Notation) > -1 ){

    // put here the code to apply the formatting

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## `onEdit` won't work with formulas

#### Unfortunately `onEdit()` will only work when a **user** edits the sheet, **not** when updated by a formula.

## Workaround: How to install an `onChange` trigger and link it to a function that changes the format of one cell based on another cell's value.

There is an installable trigger called `onChange()`:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onChange()

There are a few more steps to get it working than onEdit:

1. You have to first install the trigger - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Do this by creating another function in your script like the below:

```js
function createTrigger() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); // this will be the function to run
ScriptApp.newTrigger("changeFormat")
  .forSpreadsheet(sheet) // this is the sheet it is installed on
  .onChange() // this is the type of trigger
  .create();
}
```

You will only need to run this once. Run it. It will ask you for permissions, grant them.

2. Rename the function that changes the format of the cell to “changeFormat” as referenced above in the `createTrigger()` function, and copy/adapt this code that I based on your original code:

```js
function changeFormat() {
  
  var scoreBoard = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Scoreboard')
  var inputValue = scoreBoard.getRange('A2').getValue();
  var cellToFormat = scoreBoard.getRange('M6')
  
  if (inputValue < 10){
    cellToFormat.setFontColor("black").setFontWeight("initial");
  } else if( inputValue >= 10 && inputValue < 20 ){
    cellToFormat.setFontColor("dimgray").setFontWeight("initial");
  } else if( inputValue >= 20 && inputValue < 40 ){
    cellToFormat.setFontColor("silver").setFontWeight("initial");
  } else if( inputValue >= 40 && inputValue < 60 ){
    cellToFormat.setFontColor("palegoldenrod").setFontWeight("initial");
  } else if( inputValue >= 60 && inputValue < 80 ){
    cellToFormat.setFontColor("khaki").setFontWeight("initial");
  } else if( inputValue >= 80 && inputValue < 100 ){
    cellToFormat.setFontColor("yellow").setFontWeight("initial");
  } else if( inputValue == 100 ){
    cellToFormat.setFontColor("yellow").setFontWeight("bold");    
  }
}
```

A few things I changed about your code:

- You can make your code more succinct by assigning object notation to a variable:

```
var scoreBoard = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Scoreboard')
```

- Since you are only checking one cell for a value, you don’t need to know *what* cell has changed, only *if* a cell has changed, so you can set it as I did above:

```
var inputValue = scoreBoard.getRange('A2').getValue();
```

3. Save your code and then it should work!

#### Caveats

You can modify your function `changeFormat` to something similar to `onEdit(e)` by simply making it thus: `changeFormat(e)`. You can then interact with the `e` **BUT** it is not going to behave in the same way or contain the same information as an `e` from `onEdit`! You can `console.log(e)` to look into that further.